# Neo4j very slowly using shortestPath

Tags: performance, neo4j

I'm trying to improve the speed of query below. She is returning the data in 9 seconds. If I remove the shortestPath, the time drops to 1.5 seconds.

Does anyone know what might be wrong with my query or how to optimize shartestPath?

It's a single query:

```
MATCH (currentUser:Packer {UUID:'19443'})-[:I_Follow*0..1]->followers-[rf:Has_Backpack|Has_Contribution*0..1]->(e)
Match (e)-[rp:Has_Pocket|Has_Document*0..]->d
Match d-[rn:Say_Thanks|I_Follow|I_Favorite_Follow|I_Favorite*0..1]->a
with distinct currentUser,followers, a, last(rf + rp  + rn) as l  
Optional match shortestPath(currentUser-[:Has_Group|Has_Shared_To_Collaboration|Hub_Shared|Has_Shared|Has_Backpack|Has_Pocket|Has_Document]->a)
with  followers, a, count(a) as num,l<br><br>
OPTIONAL MATCH a-[:Hub_Comments]->()-[rf:Has_Comment]->comments   
WITH  followers, a, l, collect(comments)[0..3] as coll,count(comments) as totalComments,num

MATCH parent-[l]->a where (num > 0 or a.Permission <> 'Private') with followers, a, parent, l, coll, totalComments  order by l.Datecreate desc skip 0 limit 10
Match (owner:Packer {Username:a.Createdby})<br>
return followers, a, parent, l, coll, totalComments, owner
```

Using the profile have this data:

```
Operator | Rows | DbHits | Identifiers

Extract (0) | 3731 | 7462 |

PatternMatcher (0) | 3731 | 8386 | parent, a, l |

Filter | 3735 | 7470 | | (a> {} AUTOINT3 OR NOT (Property (a, Permission (10)) == {AUTOSTRING4})) |

Total Accesses database: 23386
```

Version: 2.1.6
nodes: 175,563
properties: 468 402
relationships: 155,284
relationship types: 38
database disk: 780 MB
usage: 2 MB

Comment: It seems odd that you're matching with `shortestPath` but the relationship definition isn't variable length.  Wouldn't that be matching whichever path of 1 hop is shortest?

Comment: Oh, also, do you have indexes in the places where you're matching keys?

Comment: Yes, I have indexes for UUID and Permission. In fact rlationship is a variable length here (e)-[rp:Has_Pocket|Has_Document*0..]->d

Comment: But the shortestPath relationship MATCH isn't variable length, right?  It's `Has_Group|Has_Shared_To_Collaboration|Hub_Shared|Has_Shared|Has_Backpack|Has_Pocket|Has_Document`

Comment: Yes, because we do not have sublevels limits in Has_Pocket relationship. But put a limit of 10 and still was very slow.

Link com detalhes do profile: https://gist.github.com/jefersonmanjos/02cb3972b4f738b42397

Comment: I removed shortestPath and changed the logic of my query. Now is returning in less than 2 seconds.

Thanks